# useReducer stockpiles component renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-stonebraker-gsyckl?file=/src/App.js), we use `useReducer` to increment a state change counter. We also track the number of component renders.

We have the option to call `dispatch` with or without updating our state. If we dispatch without updating state, our component does not re-render.

However, if at a later time we update our state, ALL of those previously empty dispatches will cause additional re-renders, released simultaneously at the time of state update.

We can see this in the example by clicking `pass` a bunch of times and then clicking `increment`. State updates once, but the component will re-render many times.

Is there a name for this delay and then release behaviour and is there any way to prevent storing/releasing these additional re-renders?

Comment: It seems `pass` does nothing visually, and therefore can be converted to `useRef` instead of a state change which causes re-rendering (as it assumes things should visually get changed). This simple change will solve all your problems.

Comment: Also, what you consider as "bad" (re-renders) is not necessarily bad. Every state change triggers a re-render, but React isn't stupid, and it compares previous state to the new state and sees no DOM changes are needed and what you're left with is just *potential* performance issues if the component has a bunch of expensive calculations (the stuff above the returned JSX part)

Comment: To your second point, I'm dispatching `onScroll` in production so those few extra renders become 1000s more.

Comment: To your first point, a bunch of complex calcs done _inside_ the reducer function which operate on our state to determine whether or not we will pass, so it's not as simple as just replacing it with `useRef`

Comment: I am the author of a tiny React node module which might help you: [react-ref-watch](https://github.com/yairEO/react-ref-watcher)

Comment: I am also the author of another one which might help (because of scroll events): [react-bouncer](https://github.com/yairEO/react-bouncer)

Comment: Firstly, wow! Super cool. I could absolutely use `react-ref-watch` to fix this, but the logic might get a bit complicated. Unfortunately I can't debounce/throttle this particular event based on my use case.

Comment: I actually just ended up swapping out `useReducer` for `useState` but kept the logic identical, and it works as expected without the additional re-renders. I'm going to keep this question open though because I still want to understand why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

Why call the reducer function on every render ? Keep it simple.
Call a initial state instead:

> const initialState = { stateChangeCount:0};

Then reference it as:

> const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(stateReducer, initialState);

Use effect is also here to help, this mean inside it you can identify when theres a render:

> export default function App() {     const renders = useRef(0);
> useEffect(() => {
> renders.current = renders.current + 1;   });

Full code ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-stonebraker-gsyckl?file=/src/App.js)):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useReducer, useRef ,useEffect } from "react";

const actions = {
  increment: "increment",
  pass: "pass"
};

const initialState = { stateChangeCount:0};



const stateReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case actions.increment:
      return { stateChangeCount: state.stateChangeCount + 1 };
    case actions.pass:
      return state;
    default:
      throw Error("Must pass valid action");
  }
};

export default function App() {  
  const renders = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    renders.current = renders.current + 1;
  });


  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(stateReducer, initialState);

  return (  
    
    <div className="App">
      CountSTATE: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(actions.increment)}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(actions.pass)}>Pass</button>
      <h1>Render count {renders.current}</h1>
      <h2>Dispatch count {state.stateChangeCount}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: FYI, your link seems to go to the original sandbox instead of your one.

Comment: I've updated the codesandbox to create my initial state  outside of my component, but this doesn't address the question that was asked. I'm already identifying when there's a re-render without `useEffect`, and it renders too much for what it should be doing!


"We see in the example by clicking pass a bunch of times and then clicking increment. State updates once, but the component will re-render many times."

Comment: thanks @toneo , Matt check the updated sandbox link and we go from there

Comment: Sandbox link is still linking to my original it seems

Comment: I copied in your code... You're correct, I apologize

Comment: The issues was my re-render counter not being in `useEffect` as you mentioned

Comment: glad that i have helped somehow

Comment: Wait a minute hold on

Comment: just in case i am getting the link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It IS still rendering though on when we click pass though otherwise why would it update the ref

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254325/discussion-between-matt-and-jmvcollaborator).

Comment: sure getting late here, i will drop u a line if you dont mind ? this is a nice thing to discuss :)